# How to check that a webservice ran successfully and it changed the status of the record to the desired one

Tags: workflow, process-builder, webservices

**Problem Statement** : We have a object by name **'Proposal Line Item'**. Now there is web service written onto the object which performs the following operation.

1) When the 'Status' of the Line item is set to **'To be published'** at that time the web service picks up the records for processing.

2) When the web service sends the record out then the 'Status' of line item is **'Publishing'**. Usually this step takes approx 2 minutes.

3) If the web service send the reply back successfully then the line item 'Status' is **'Published'**.

4) If the web service fails then the 'Status' of line item is **'Publish Fail'**.

Now the issue happening is that sometimes this process is resulting into 'Time out' error and no status changes are happening to the line item record after it is set to **'Publishing'**.

We want to write some workflow/process which can check the status of the line item **15 minutes** after the status has been set to **'Publishing'**. And if line item is still in the same status then set it back to **'To be published'** so that the web service can again pick it up for processing. Now with process bulider/workflow it is not possible to check the status of the record **15 minutes** after it's status was **'Publishing'** . Is there any other approach with which this can be achieved ?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the 15 minutes might be tricky as process builder and workflow rules are usually based on hours - not sure off the top of my head if  you can use fractions of hours - so 0.25 hours later

Comment: @DaveHumm:  But first of all how to check that after 15min or an hour the status changed to published/publish error or not? We can put the time based actions but how to put the time based chaek ?

Comment: You have to record the time when the status has been changed to Publishing. You can create a datetime field for this and put the timestamp using a trigger or a workflow.

Comment: @SantanuHalder : I will try your approach but this will required lot of customization . Please let me know if there can be any alternate solution too. Thanks!

Comment: How are your 'Time out' errors recorded? Are they just written to a debug log or are they written back to a field on the record or better yet, to a custom error log object? If to the record, you can create workflow & if to a custom object, you can use a trigger/queueable pattern to query records in the custom object to update the record then remove log entries.

Comment: @crmprogdev: The timeout errors are getting recorded in debug logs only. I have tried to create a time-based workflow to see to test that if I change the status of the record from publishing to something else before the time mentioned to fire the field update , then the field update goes off from the workflow queue. But I was not able to provide the condition of 0.25 to limit time of 15min as suggested by Davehumm so I had to use 1hour.

Comment: Can you post the method from your web service that reports the timeout error which gets written to the debug log? Perhaps even better to post the entire class if not too large. If you can do that, you'll likely get a better response to your question on how to handle/solve your issue. You could also use a trigger to set off a queueable with a start time of 15 min from NOW() to query the records in the transaction for success.